# I want to add shapes to a toolboxcontrol then be able to drop them into a diagramcntrole

Tags: c#, devexpress, customizing

want to add items (shapes) into a tool box and then be able to drag and drop them into a different diagram control the diagrame controle and the toolboxcontrol each one is in a different pannel

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the documentation articles:

- [How to: Change the Set of Shapes Available In the Shapes Panel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116966/Controls-and-Libraries/Diagrams/Examples/How-to-Change-the-Set-of-Shapes-Available-In-the-Shapes-Panel)
- [How to: Create Custom Diagram Containers and Register them in the Toolbox and Ribbon Gallery](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/118081/Controls-and-Libraries/Diagrams/Examples/How-to-Create-Custom-Diagram-Containers-and-Register-them-in-the-Toolbox-and-Ribbon-Gallery).

If these articles do not help, please [contact the DevExpress Support team directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: i've found some codes that could help me, i've tryed copy/past them in form.cs but it continuously generate errors could u help me to know where should i copy/past them

Comment: @Brendon Such as: Unable to resolve type 'DevExpress.XtraDiagram.DiagramControl                                                                                      or                                                                                                                                               Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) T357857                                                         and others

Comment: I've fixed this error : "The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "//// By upgrading the application and devexpress (just uninstalled and installed (devexpress) it suggested the upgrade though i've reinstalled the same version ..